# Magento checkout blank page

Tags: magento-1.8

My magento shop works fine, but sometimes (2 times on this month) there is blank page instead of it in Google Chrome and Only the first step in FireFox. When I press continue button nothing happen. Previous times I fixed this problem by increasing memory_limit (it was less then recomended) and rebooting server. But now memory limit is 2048M it is more than enough and problem still occurs. Somebody can help me?

Comment: Have you checked your error log to see what the problem might be?

Comment: @unknown09 Please transform your solution to an answer and mark it as accepted. After that, don't forget to delete your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved (I hope so) I've checked the apache log, and found 'zend_mm_heap corrupted' error. The solution was to increase the 'output_buffering' value in the php.ini